# Marketing Cloud Connect - using date/time fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

When working with Marketing Cloud Connect, is there anything in particular you should be mindful of, when working with date/time fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is - in my example, I'm based out of Denmark, which means I am in GMT+1, but more over I am also in a country that has summer and winter time - which poses a challenge.

**The key observation:**

- The time that is written in a data extension created by a Salesforce
  Entry Event used in Journey Builder
- ***is not the same***
- as the time written for the same record into a Synchronized Data
  Extension

For example:

- An event in Salesforce is scheduled to be 10.00 AM local time
- This comes over at 08.00 AM in the SF Entry Event DE (due to integration users locale)
- And the same event comes over as 02.00 AM in the Synchronized Data Extension, which is corresponding to the server / system time in Marketing Cloud

Luckily, there is an easy way to overcome this using AMPscript (and note, you need ampscript to correctly portray date/time originating from within Salesforce)

You need two things:

- A data extension (Time_Offset)
- Some AMPscript

**The data extension**
This is configured with 3 fields:

- Locale (Text, 10) : This is the primary key
- Adjustment (Number) : This is where you enter the adjustment
- Explanation (Text, 150) : Used to explain what the line represents

As I am only creating a solution for Denmark, I only have 2 records in here, but you can have as many as you need. They look something like this:

DK-trig | 2 | This is used for SF triggered sends, write 2 in summer time, 1 in winter
DK-sync | 8 | This is used for date-time from SF Sync DE's, write 8 in summer time, 7 in winter

**The associated script**
Below is a piece of ampscript you can use to pull in fields an adjust the time. 
The first script is for modifying date/time when pulling from a synchronized data extension.

```
%%[
SET @EventDE = "ent.Event_Salesforce"
SET @EventID = EventId /*You need the ID to pull right record from ent.Event_SalesforcE */ 

    SET @EventRows = LookupRows(@EventDE, "Id", @EventID)
    IF RowCount(@EventRows) > 0 THEN
        SET @Event = Row(@EventRows, 1)
        SET @SystemEventDate = Field(@Event, "StartDateTime")
        SET @TimeAdjustment = Lookup("Time_Offset", "Adjustment", "Locale", "DK-sync")
        SET @EventDate = DateAdd(@SystemEventDate, @TimeAdjustment, "H")
            SET @WeekDay = FormatDate(@EventDate, "ddddd", "", "da")
            SET @StartDate = FormatDate(@EventDate, "dd/MM-YY", "")
            SET @StartTime = FormatDate(@EventDate, "", "HH:MM")
    ENDIF
]%%
Your meeting will be held %%=v(@WeekDay) the %%=v(@StartDate)=%% at %%=v(@StartTime)=%%
```

The second piece of code is for when you are modifying a date/time field located in your data extension (typically for use with Journey Builder)

```
%%[
SET @SystemEventDate = Event:StartDateTime
SET @TimeAdjustment = Lookup("Time_Offset", "Adjustment", "Locale", "DK-trig")

SET @EventDate = DateAdd(@SystemEventDate, @TimeAdjustment, "H")
    SET @WeekDay = FormatDate(@EventDate, "ddddd", "", "da")
    SET @StartDate = FormatDate(@EventDate, "dd/MM-YY", "")
    SET @StartTime = FormatDate(@EventDate, "", "HH:MM")
]%%
Your meeting will be held %%=v(@WeekDay) the %%=v(@StartDate)=%% at %%=v(@StartTime)=%%
```

Hopefully, this will save some, some hairpulling when working with similar scenarios